# PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to delete XML empty nodes when insert a table in stored procedure. I have tried some code, it throw error as

> PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB.

So please any one help me to find out the clob error. int_content column variable is clob only.

```
INSERT
      INTO int_details
        (
          int_rid,
          int_cpy,
          int_brn,
          int_sre,
          int_ree,
          int_type,
          int_filename,
          int_content,
          int_status,
          int_remarks,
          int_blob_content
        )
        VALUES
        (
          v_int_rid,
          p_cpy_rid,
          1,
          p_inty_rid,
          null,
          null,
          TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DDMMYYHH24MISS')||'.xml',
          deleteXML(v_clob, '//*[not(text())][not(*)]').getclobval(),
          'Active',
          'EDI Generated on'||TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYY HH24:MI:SS'),
          v_blob
        );
```

Comment: What's going on with those 3 `null`in the middle of the values list? It looks like you're missing at least one comma. Why concatenate a null onto a string? It's a non-op. Also I recommend you make your values list 11 lines (don't put a new line in your string concats) or comment your values so you know what they are when there are a lot of concats

Comment: yep changed now please check and give any idea

Comment: The first TO_CHAR has || without anything before it, that’s not proper?

Comment: But now that you've added missing commas to all 3 nulls you have a string concat with nothing on the left of it and you have 12 values being inserted into 11 columns

Comment: for null,i will give value after some time.. now i want to know the reason of clob issue in           deleteXML(v_clob, '//*[not(text())][not(*)]').getclobval(), line

Comment: What are you trying to do with that xpath? That's really rather a separate question. Consider closing this one off if my answer is a reputable or helpful and asking another question like "how to I construct an xpath that matches all nodes in a document that have no text or children?"

Comment: Thank you for all of you.. for your correct answer. caius jard  If i know every thing i did't ask any questions.so in future i didn't ask anything to here. i will take care of mine..hope you and others responsibility is correct my code and me not blaming

Comment: If someone makes an answer you feel is correct for you, click the grey tick to turn it green. If they wrote something helpful, click the up arrow. Many answers can be helpful, but only one can be ticked. In time you will probably write more answers than questions, to help out others who need your expertise :) welcome to the site!

Comment: yep but i did't do that.. its not working for me... thanks for your advice. i Know the above. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

For big messy inserts lay them out with the same number of lines in the values and columns lists:

```
INSERT
  INTO int_details
    (
      int_rid,
      int_cpy,
      int_brn,
      int_sre,
      int_ree,
      int_type,
      int_filename,
      int_content,
      int_status,
      int_remarks,
      int_blob_content
    )
    VALUES
    (
      v_int_rid,
      p_cpy_rid,
      1,
      p_inty_rid,
      null,
      null,
      TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DDMMYYHH24MISS')||'.xml',
      deleteXML(v_clob, '//*[not(text())][not(*)]').getclobval(),
      'Active',
      'EDI Generated on'||TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYY HH24:MI:SS'),
      v_blob
    );
```

Note that I have removed one of your nulls to get down to 11 values. THIS MAY NOT BE CORRECT. I can't know what you want on this case; you have to solve it properly

Or comment the hardcides values, or separate the blocks of code into visually countable things, when things go multiline

```
INSERT
  INTO int_details
    (
      int_rid,
      int_cpy,
      int_brn,
      int_sre,
      int_ree,
      int_type,
      int_filename,
      int_content,
      int_status,
      int_remarks,
      int_blob_content
    )
    VALUES
    (
      v_int_rid,
      p_cpy_rid,
      1, --int_brn
      p_inty_rid,
      null, --int_ree
      null, --int_type

      --int_filename
      null
        ||TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DDMMYYHH24MISS')||'.xml',

      --int_content
      deleteXML(v_clob, '//*[not(text())][not(*)]').getclobval(),

      --int_status
      'Active',

      --int_remarks
      'EDI Generated on'
      ||TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYY HH24:MI:SS'),

      v_blob
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yehh i have corrected. but still showing same error only